# Java Mockito Test Static property assign with function

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I will make a Junit test on the following class

```
public class myClass{ 
     public final static String myProp = getMyrPop();

     public static String getMyProp() {
          return "someData";
     }
}
```

When i try to make a test, i can't mock the function getMyProp(){}

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class ExternalIdUtilsTest {
    @Before
    public void init(){
        Mockito.when(MyClass.getMyProp()).thenReturn("Albert");
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        assertEquals(1,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error / unexpected behavior?

Comment: That's not the right way of mocking static method. Mockito itself doesn't allow static method mocking. You need to use PowerMockito